# Vulnerabilities in Scala web applications

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, vulnerability

I want to create a server side web application using Scala.  Are there any classes of web vulnerabilities that are unique to Scala?

I tried to search on the web for Scala-specific vulnerabilities, but I couldn't find any vulnerabilities that are not shared with Java: everything I found is also an issue for web applications written in Java.  I know about the OWASP top 10 vulnerabilities, but I want to know if there are any Scala-specific risks that I need to know about when writing web applications in Scala.

Comment: Scala compiles into java bytecode. That's why the vulnerabilities are shared, and not unique to Scala. Just like any compiled language, the source code does not have vulnerabilities, per se, but the resulting compiled code does.

Comment: btw, OWASP top 10 isn't quite relevant to Scala, though there is some overlap to all coding

Comment: Check this http://blog.codacy.com/2015/12/11/9-scala-security-issues-you-should-know-about/#gs.Z2R6tHQ

Comment: Hash maps are sources of DoS vulnerabilities when working with Scala collections: https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11203